# How to write that HQL right

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Hi I am trying to write this where and fetch query and I get an error

```
 Query query = session.createQuery("from Device d where d.customerRefId=:customerId " +
                    "left join fetch d.tradeInOldDevice ");                    
  query.setParameter("customerId", "myId");  
 Set<Device> customerDevices= (Set<Device>) query.list();
```

the error:

```
2013-09-24 12:18:45,753 ERROR PARSER:56 - line 1:98: unexpected token: left
```

Thats Device entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Devices")
public class Device implements Serializable, IHidingDeletable {

...

  @ManyToOne(optional = true,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Customer owningCompany

 @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tradeInOldDevice")
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private Device tradeInOldDevice;

..
```

And That's Customer:

```
public class Customer extends AbstractCustomer {...}


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "Customers")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public abstract class AbstractCustomer implements IVersionized, Serializable {

   @Id
    protected String customerRefId;
```

Any idea?

Comment: I think you have left some text while posting the code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The join should come before the where clause:

```
    Query query = session.createQuery("from Device d left join " + 
    "fetch d.tradeInOldDevice od where d.customer.customerRefId=:customerId");

    query.setParameter("customerId", "myId");
    Set<Device> customerDevices= (Set<Device>) query.list();
```

Comment: Then I get different error: 2013-09-24 12:26:41,850 ERROR PARSER:56 -  Path expected for join!

Comment: @rayman Do you have an association established in your mapping between `Device` and the entity for `TradeInOldDevice`?

Comment: You asking if I have inside Device customerRefId? if thats what you asking than no.. I got the customerRefId inside Device table in the DB

Comment: @rayman What I mean is that Device should have a field `tradeInOldDevice` and this field should be marked as an association, so OneToOne or OneToMany.  I'm guessing this may be a self referencing association if the `tradeInOldDevice` field is of type `Device`

Comment: Ahh so yes.. I have tradeInOldDevice as association and It's @OneTone. and you were also right it's field is of type Device

Comment: @rayman Try adding the alias to the joined entity. Its very subtle but I updated the answer above with `od`

Comment: Ok that worked actually I had another fetch there which missied the alias. but now I get this error: could not resolve property: owningCompany_customerRefId

Comment: Is `customerRefId` a field on `Device` if so what is its type?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I guess I missed something basic here. customerRefId - is the coulmn name in the DB. Inside Device I have Customer field which contains the customerRefId. how could I join between the two within the HQL?

Comment: Thats inside Customer:  @Id
    protected String customerRefId;

Comment: Ok I edited my question with the customer and device entities. this time I got that error: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ServicesServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: antlr.collections.AST.getLine()I

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37932/discussion-between-rayman-and-kevin-bowersox)